# iOS application-Show a Custom Interactive View like a system alert on the screen when a push notification is received

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, xamarin

My application uses push notification for communication and it's a NON VOIP based application ,I wanted to know if the below features can be acheived by some means as it's communication part is important in my app .

1) When the app is not active, On receive of push notification , can a Custom User interface or ViewController can be shown instead of the usual notification which comes in the notification tray on top of phone.?

2) And once the custom UI or ViewController comes up , can i interact with it to launch my app.?

3) I understood the VOIP based app's can do this like Whatsapp and Skype, but can a NON VOIP  based app can do the same, since my app deals with  communication using notification currently  ?

Thanks , any help or suggestions for this.

Comment: You can add a notification content app extension in an iOS 12+ using UserNotificationsUI to add interactive content to notifications (iOS 10 & 11 you can add custom content, but not interactions) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications

Comment: HI @SushiHangover, thanks for the suggestion. But I wanted a screen to be presented at the centre of screen like a phone call which will not be missed by any chance by the user as OLA Driver application does in Android.

Comment: You can not do that....